# Override wp_unique_filename

Tags: php, wordpress

How do you pass a callback parameter to a WordPress function?

wp_unique_filename takes 3 parameters (`$dir`, `$filename`, and `$unique_filename_callback = null`). I can't for the life of me figure out how to pass `$unique_filename_callback`.

I've tried both `add_action` and `add_filter`, each with 10/3

```
add_action( 'wp_unique_filename', 'my_unique_filename', 10, 3 );
add_filter( 'wp_unique_filename', 'my_unique_filename', 10, 3 );
```

And then

```
function my_unique_filename( $dir, $filename, my_unique_filename_cb ){
}
function my_unique_filename_c(){
}
```

No matter what I put for that this parameter, I get a parse error that it's expecting a variable. I've tried:

```
my_unique_filename_cb
'my_unique_filename_cb'
my_unique_filename_cb()
'my_unique_filename_cb()'
```

#### UPDATE

I'm thinking it needs to be passed as an override to `wp_handle_upload` which takes an array of overrides, extracts it, and passes `$unique_filename_callback` as an argument later in the function. In that case, how can I pass my function as a parameter in an array (if this is the solution):

```
function my_wp_handle_upload( $file, array( 'unique_filename_callback' => myfunction ) ){
  //Which would then extract unique_filename_callback to $unique_filename_callback
  //and pass it to wp_unique_filename as the third parameter
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wp_unique_filename()` checks if a callback function is specified, exists and is callable. Args passed are `$dir`, `$name`, and `$ext`. Here's a (useless) example:

```
function my_unique_filename_function( $dir = '', $filename = 'bar.exe' )
{
    echo wp_unique_filename( $dir, $filename, 'my_unique_filename_callback' );
}

function my_unique_filename_callback( $dir, $name, $ext )
{
    return $name . $ext;
}

my_unique_filename_function(); // echoes bar.exe
my_unique_filename_function( '', 'qux.gif' ); // echoes qux.gif
```

Specifying a custom callback for `wp_unique_filename()` used by `wp_handle_upload()` (adapted [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_handle_upload) example):

```
$uploadedfile = $_FILES['file'];
$upload_overrides = array( 'unique_filename_callback' => 'my_unique_filename_callback' );
$movefile = wp_handle_upload( $uploadedfile, $upload_overrides );
if ( $movefile ) {
    echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.";
    var_dump( $movefile);
} else {
    echo "Possible file upload attack!";
}
```

Comment: So what hook would I used for my_unique_filename_function? I tried wp_unique_filename, but it's not firing so I can't test this. Thanks!

Comment: I didn't read your Q thoroughly enough. Are you trying to modify `wp_unique_filename`'s behaviour as it is used in WP core functions?

Comment: I'd like to pass a custom callback to run my own unique filename counter instead of using WordPress' default one. Reason being, I need to check a different directory to run the file count increment instead of WordPress checking the uploads directory.

Comment: If you're using `wp_unique_filename()` directly in a function, you can do whatever you want. In WP core the only case you can actually specify a custom callback for `wp_unique_filename()` is when you're using `wp_handle_upload()`, e.g. `wp_handle_upload( $files['file'], array( 'unique_filename_callback' => 'my_unique_filename_callback' ) );`

Comment: I just came to that realization and updated the question. I am still getting the Parse error: parse error, expecting `'&'' or `"variable (T_VARIABLE)"' when passing the function name like I thought and you just commented. (I appreciate your ongoing help!!)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm marking it correct even though I'm running into an issue I could use help with if you have any thoughts. By the time the file hits my unique callback (and even by the time it hits my wp_handle_upload), it has already been renamed. Any thoughts?